# how to remove the image tag from string

Tags: php, smarty, cs-cart

I need to remove the image from the description

I have the following code to display the description. Here description contains combinations editor contents.Here i want only display 1000 characters and not display image .

```
{$row.description|substr:0:1000|cat:'..'  nofilter }
```

how to i do . Please help me.

Comment: which editor you are using?

Comment: redactor editor. I have the redactor editor in backend. in front end only i need to  hide the image

Comment: I fixed this issue. By using {$row.description|strip_tags|substr:0:1000|cat:'..'}

Comment: this is the same code you were using?

Comment: i use strip_tags instead of nofilter

Comment: great, can you update your answer for others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68122/discussion-between-prabhash-and-soniya-kaliappan).